# Clearing a made list

Tags: list

I am adding to a list as I execute a number of functions.  How can I clear the elements in the list by calling a function for such task.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. In particular what you mean by "clear the elements in the list". Are you asking about list-structure modification (a destructive operation)? Or setting the value of some variable to the empty list (`nil`)? Or something else?

Comment: I am continually adding to a list and want to refresh its contents.  Should I use  `(setq slist '())` or something like `(setq slist nil)`?  Or something else?

Comment: `(eq '() nil)` -> `t`. So your alternative is not one.

Comment: Right.  My alternative is not one?  What does that mean?

Comment: Looks like `(setq slist '())` is more popular.

Comment: What gigiair means is that `nil` *is* `'()`. The choice is one of style. I would agree with you that when you specifically mean "a list with no elements" `'()'` is slightly preferable.

Comment: In Emacs Lisp there's no need to quote `()` (or `nil`). It's self-evaluating, like `t`.

Comment: What about `defvar`?  I have been using `(defvar slist '())`.